# Encoding large numbers with json_encode in php

Tags: php, json

I have a php script that outputs a json-encoded object with large numbers (greater than PHP_MAX_INT) so to store those numbers internally, I have to store them as strings.  However, I need them to be shown as un-quoted numbers to the client.

I've thought of several solutions, many of which haven't worked.  Most of the ideas revolve around writing my own JSON encoder, which I have done already, but don't want to take the time to change all the places I have `json_encode` to instead say `my_json_encode`.

Since I have no control over the server, I cannot turn remove the JSON library.  I cannot undeclare `json_encode`, nor can I rename it.  Is there any easy way to handle all this, or is the best option to just go through each and every file and rename all the method calls?

Comment: Don't you have find/replace for using my_json_encode?

Comment: It seems like more of a hassle than other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I had was to use my own json_encode method renamed to my_json_encode, and then change everywhere that called that method.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript being loosely typed, why the need to control the type in the JSON data?  What are you doing with this number in javascript, and would `parseInt\parseFloat` not be able to make the leap from string to number on the client side?

Comment: Except it's not javascript, and I don't have control over the client code.  The code is running on handheld devices that I can't easily update.  The fix needs to be server-side.